# Requesting videos for pronunciation (on topic)?

Tags: discussion

Here is the question, which is related to self-directed learning of the pronunciation of some characters in the Japanese alphabet.

> I've been looking for videos on pronunciation for these sounds in
>   Japanese alphabet ゐ, ゑ, and ぢ, but couldn't find any, are those not
>   being used in the modern Japanese alphabet? If not, where can I find
>   video lessons teaching their pronunciation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think rather than only asking for resources (off-topic), just ask your question — answers may or may not include links to videos or other sites. (You can always state that links to videos would be a welcome addition to answers.)

---

As for your question, we have a number of related questions already:

#### ゐ and ゑ

- [Modern names of the obsolete kana ゑ and ゐ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2499/1628)
- [In which dialects have the sounds "ゐ" (wi) and "ゑ" (we) been preserved, and are their kana still occasionally seen?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/376/1628)

#### ぢ

- [What are the differences between じ and ぢ, and ず and づ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1254/1628)
- [四つ仮名 yotugana - pronunciation difference](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45001/1628)

#### tldr

ゐ and ゑ are obsolete & for all modern pronunciation purposes ゐ = い, ゑ = え, ぢ = じ.